# Leaflet Overlay Image dragging and resizing

Tags: javascript, resize, leaflet, draggable

I want to drag/drop the image overlay and resize(change the bounds by dragging it from corners). I'm using the draggable function for this purpose, the similar way as it is described [Here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3883) in Question. But, I couldn't find the new bounds in 'e', after the drag ends